# c pointers double pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct test
{
    int data;
    struct test *next;
};
void main()
{

    struct test *head=(struct test *)malloc(sizeof(struct test));
    struct test **ref=&head;

    head->data=5;
    head->next=NULL;
    printf("\n %d \n %d",head->data,head->next);
    printf("\n %d \n %d",**ref->data,**ref->next);



}
```

Explanation:

I've tried the above piece of code.

Isn't `**ref` same as `*head`? If not why?

Also the compiler is throwing an error at the second `printf` saying that `data` and `next` are not part of a `structure` or a `union`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: without any programming aspect, in case `**ref same as *head`, then why do you think that extra `*` is there, at all?

Comment: In other words, you have one too many `*` in your version of `printf("\n %d \n %p",(*ref)->data,(*ref)->next);` and you need to surround the pointer in parenthesis to have correct operator precedence apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two errors, one syntactical (you use arrow notation when you should use dot notation), and the other has to do with [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

The selection operators `->` and `.` have higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`. That means the expression `**ref->data` is equivalent to `**(ref->data)`. This is of course nonsense and will not build as `data` is not a pointer.

You have two options:

1. Use e.g. `(*ref)->data`
2. Use e.g. `(**ref).data`.

I would go with option 1 as `ref` "references" a *pointer* to the structure, that syntax is more inline with what you do, IMO.

---

On an unrelated note, you should not use the `"%d"` format when printing pointers, you should be using `"%p"`. See e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Answer (score 1):

`**ref` is a pointer to a pointer to a `struct test`, `*head` is a pointer to a `struct test`.

The error is there, because whene referencing, `**ref` is of type `struct test` and you should use the dot `.` to get to a member of the struct:

```
  (**ref).data
```

`head` is a pointer to a `struct test`, and you can correctly use the `->` operator there.